# Override onbeforeunload (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I try to override `window.onbeforeunload` of this link http://lpfr.quizir.com/lp.aspx?LpID=332354&PartnerID=weedo

The script is located here : http://lpfr.quizir.com/scripts/exittraffic.js
`window.onbeforeunload = DisplayExitSplash;`

This link is open in a popup, then when I tried to change the link in the popup or close the popup, I can't.

`var xwin = window.open(http://lpfr.quizir.com/lp.aspx?LpID=332354&PartnerID=weedo)`

Generally, this works:
`xwin.onbeforeunload = function(){}`

But it doesn't work on this specific link >_<

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: So when the user wants to navigate away from your site, you want to hijack the browser and redirect them to an advertiser instead?

Comment: It is not mywebsite !!! (i can't edit my original post :( )
I try to override the onbeforeunload event of this site

Comment: `xwin.setInterval("PreventExitSplash=1",1);` will help in your case, judging by the included code at http://lpfr.quizir.com/scripts/exittraffic.js

Answer (score 1):

onbeforeunload you can just use operators and return because of preventing people from spamming.

So you can't use `window.scrollTo`, `window.alert` and `document.location.href`.

Just spammers want to use these functions onbeforeunload. Remember the client want to leave the page and don't want to close alert windows and get redirected.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand what you said (i'm french)
Just to be clear, this http://lpfr.quizir.com/lp.aspx?LpID=332354&PartnerID=weedo it's not my website, and i want to override this annoying onbeforeunload of its

Answer (score 1):

To remove all handlers for that event you should remove the DOM level 0 event like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

like Nico sugests

But also the other ways of event handling like so.

Depending on what browser you use you could do

```
window.removeEventListener( "beforeunload" );
```

On Chrome Firefox and other "W3c compliant browsers"
or

```
window.detachEvent( "onbeforeunload" );
```

On Internet Explorer 6 (i think) and up.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran this and had no issues leaving the page

```
window.onbeforeunload = null
```

Comment: This link is open in a popup, then when i tried to change the link in the popup or close the popup, i can't.

var xwin = window.open(http://lpfr.quizir.com/lp.aspx?LpID=332354&PartnerID=weedo)

Generally, this works :
xwin.onbeforeunload = function(){}


xwin.onbeforeunload = null doesn't work for me